# How to select values that already selected in autocomplete material ui?

Tags: material-ui

I'm using Material UI Autocomplete, and get stuck with this issue. In the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#autocomplete-api), it says that "The value must have reference equality with the option in order to be selected". And I did exactly what it said but seems like it is not working.

- Here are my options
  [image]
- Here is my value
  [image]
- Currently
  [image]
- Expected
  [image]

```
    <Autocomplete
     disableCloseOnSelect={true}
     multiple
     options={techList}
     getOptionLabel={(options) => options.techName}
     value={newValueDialog}
     onChange={(e, tech) => {
      this.handleChangeValueDialog(tech);
     }}
     popupIcon={false}
     closeIcon={false}
     renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
     value.map((option, index) => (
      <Chip
        color="primary"
        variant="outlined"
        label={option.techName}
        {...getTagProps({ index })}
        deleteIcon={<ClearIcon />}
      />
     ))
     }
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      variant="outlined"
      placeholder="Technology"
      fullWidth
     />
   )}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using a custom object, ensure equality with your own implementation.

https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#autocomplete-api

[image: getOptionSelected]

You must implement the "getOptionSelected" method

```
    getOptionSelected={(option, value) =>
      option.techName === value.techName
    }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-vh5ns

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-sound-5j4oy?file=/src/App.js
here is my code. I passing techList and valueTech form parents component to child component. It works in codesandbox but in my code it not.

Comment: I have solved the problem. My material-ui/lap is an old version. Upgrade to the latest version and everything works fine. Thank you.